# Using Groovy Strings as SQL select statements

Tags: mysql, groovy

Database Mysql , version 5.5.17.JDBC driver version 5.1.28 
Code with Gstring:

```
def p = "id"

def row = sql.firstRow("select $p from Model")

print row
```

result:

```
[id:id] **!**
```

Code without Gstring:

```
def row = sql.firstRow("select id from Model")

print row
```

result:

```
[id:1]
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy is escaping the `p` as it treats it as a Sql parameter

Try using [`Sql.expand`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#expand%28java.lang.Object%29) like so:

```
def p = 'id'
def row = sql.firstRow( "select ${Sql.expand( p )} from Model" )
```

Comment: @DavidHofmann thanks , also works next solutions: sql.firstRow("select $p from Model" as String) ,sql.firstRow("select $p from Model".toString())

Comment: @user2187298 Yeah, both of those work as you then pass a `String` to `firstRow` instead a Groovy String which the `Sql` class tries to help you with :-)